# Spring 3.2 - Project fails to load when @EnableAsync is added to @Configuration class

Tags: java, spring

I need a method of my bean be be executed asynchronously. For that, I added the `@Async` annotation to my bean method and `@EnableAsync` on `@Configuration` annotated class but since then, my project has stopped loading with the following error:

```
ERROR 2014-12-10 17:03:26 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader:331 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.softech.dms.service.DetailService com.softech.dms.config.WebSecurityConfig.detailService; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'detailService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.softech.dms.service.UserService com.softech.dms.service.DetailService.userService; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.softech.dms.service.CustomerService com.softech.dms.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.customerService; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.softech.dms.service.FolderServicecom.softech.dms.service.impl.CustomerServiceImpl.folderService; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'folderServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.softech.dms.service.BookmarkService com.softech.dms.service.impl.FolderServiceImpl.bookmarkFolderService; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bookmarkServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.softech.dms.service.DocumentService com.softech.dms.service.impl.BookmarkServiceImpl.documentService; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'documentServiceImpl': Bean with name 'documentServiceImpl' has been injected into other beans
        [documentHistoryServiceImpl,sharedDocumentServiceImpl] in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use
        the final version of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

When I remove `@EnableAsync` annotation, everything works perfectly again. Please suggest if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 5):

Try putting lazy annotation to the object where you are autowiring. It solved for me

```
@Autowired
@Lazy(value=true)
MyService servObj;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `default-lazy-init="true"`  to your **xml configuration file**.

This article give some directions about the **circular dependency** problem:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/resolve-circular-dependency

Comment: I am using annotation based configuration. How should I go about doing the above configuration ?

Comment: Maybe in spring 3.2 it is default, but for previous versions the annotation should be enable by the "<context:annotation-config/>" in the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

don't use @Lazy(value=true).

There are two important cases for implement @Async annotation.

1. you should use @Async for public methods.
2. You should call the public method from another class. You shouldn't call the public 
   method from same class of the public method.